# Manipulating borders within a range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with  a 3x3 grid that has a border around the entire grid as well as horizontal and vertical cell borders within the grid. Using a VBA subroutine, I want to alter the borders to remove the interior borders but leave the surrounding borders as they are. To do this, I wrote the following snippet

```
With Selection
    .Clear
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Merge
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

With the selection being the 3x3 grid, when this snippet is executed, it does remove the horizontal and vertical interior lines but it also removes the outer border as well. How do I keep the outer border intact? I suppose recreating it is an option but the problem is that there are actually a number of these 3x3 grids and, depending upon where on the sheet they're located, each of the four outer borders can assume different line weights. I'd rather not have to figure out which weight to use based on the grid location if it isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code without

```
Selection.Clear
```